# Is it possible to use a in VirtualBox clone into a different OS?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I a super newby in VM world.

My host operating system is macOS and the guest is Ubuntu 18.04.

If I clone the guest VM, would I be able to use it in a different host with Windows 10?

I'm guessing it is not possible, but I need to hear it from an expert.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes. The basic idea of is that you provide an abstracted, virtualized hardware environment to the VM. As long as that remains the same you shouldn't face issues. So using Virtual Box on Windows 10 would allow you to run the Ubuntu guest that you created with Virutal Box on MacOS. Reality is a bit more complex - e.g. an OS might supporting being spun up on different hardware and there are converters for disk files.

Comment: @Seth : so you suggest to give it a try and open my Ubuntu VM .vdi file in Windows 10 host machine. Is it safe? because I'd need to do it on my boss Laptop :-)

Comment: I move VMware virtual machines like this. Move the whole folder to another machine so as to get all the files. It should just run on the new machine.